# Slow music playback through external monitor speaker

Tags: sound, hdmi, external-monitor

I'am using external monitor connected to my notebook through HDMI, I'm currently running ubuntu 16.04.

At first everything worked just fine, but some time later this issue started to appear. When I play anything through speaker in the monitor it's kind of slow (I can actually see on on the playback that every 1 second of playback takes at least 2 seconds), when I switch to internal speaker it's fine.

Only way for me to solve this is to reboot system, than it works fine for random time.

I tried to use different music apps (audacious, vlc, gnome-music, rhythmbox) but this issue appears on every one of them. Also didn't find anything in the settings or some fix guides on the internet.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: first I was using ubuntu 14.04 and I thought it  is a driver issue, when I upgraded to 16.04 I had the same issue as you described. my monitor is Samsung p2370MS